# Is a Trip still considered successful even if the target is already prone?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat-maneuver

I already know that using trip as an AoO against a foe while they're trying to stand up doesn't cancel their standing-up action, they still make it to their feet.  However, Greater Trip permits an AoO when you make a successful trip, *not* when an opponent falls prone from standing.  The developers have [issued errata](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5ldw0?The-FAQ-That-Time-Forgot) very specifically stating that these are separate events - separate enough to permit two AoOs against the same target if the tripper has both Greater Trip and Vicious Stomp.

If they're that dissimilar, and nothing in either the [trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Trip) nor the [prone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Prone) descriptions say otherwise, then a trip can be successful (and thus proc an AoO from Greater Trip, though not Vicious Stomp) even if the foe is already prone, right?

I'm building a character with a class from a third-party book that gains an animal companion and can select class features to give their companion access to all their own Combat feats, which means I can get Greater Trip onto my wolf companion despite the Int requirement.  I also have a combo in mind that uses the same principle of successful trips against prone targets using Relentless Shot to allow me more battlefield control, since I'm not exactly a damage dealer.

Comment: Edited that all into the question, where you should be editing it in yourself instead of comments...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it's neither errata nor rules text...

## [James Jacobs says No](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2lz17?Can-you-trip-a-prone-person#27)

In the 2011 Paizo messageboard thread ["Can You Trip a Prone Person?"](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2lz17?Can-you-trip-a-prone-person#1) *Pathfinder* creative director James Jacobs says

> You can't trip someone who is prone. Just like you can't put a sleeping person to sleep, kill someone who's dead, or so on. This is a case where, I would hope, common sense would remove the need to write things down.

Thus, while the printed rules may not *disallow* tripping a prone foe, at least one of *Pathfinder*'s developers is against the idea of tripping a prone foe. Also possibly of interest, *Pathfinder* lead designer Jason Bulmahn chimes in on the attack-a-foe-while-he's-standing issue in [this thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l0rq&page=3?TripLocking-Doesnt-Work-Official-Ruling-or-Not#111) from 2010. (*Caution:* Thread is 12 pages long.)

Comment: yeah, we've done the attack-a-foe-while-he's-standing-up thing in another question on this site, too, IIRC.  That quote isn't exactly an errata, you're right, but I'll take JJ's word as word of God barring a more official source.  It's a shame, I was really hopeful - oh well, two AoOs on a trip is enough, no need to chain them further.

Comment: As an aside, a developer of the d20-system-derived 1st-edition *Spycraft* who was a big video game fighting game fan wrote some (deviously clever) martial arts rules in that game's *Pan-Asian Collective* sourcebook *intending* prone foes be knocked, somehow, *even proner*. So, I guess, there's some precedent, sort of?