# Trip Attack of Opportunity Chaining

Tags: pathfinder-1e

**Can I use a Trip for my Attack of Opportunity when an opponent is standing from prone to provoke more attacks of opportunity from *[Greater Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-trip-combat-final/)* and *[Vicious Stomp](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/vicious-stomp-combat/)*?**

Player A has taken, amongst others, the feats: *[Combat Reflexes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/combat-reflexes-combat/)*, *[Greater Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-trip-combat-final/)*, and *[Vicious Stomp](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/vicious-stomp-combat/)*, and has enough Dexterity to make at least 3 AoO per round.

An example combat flow where this situation could occur:

- Player A trips Opponent B, AoO chaos ensues.
- Opponent B attempts to Stand Up, provoking an AoO.
- Player A uses an AoO on prone Opponent B, to perform a Trip attack.
- Opponent B provokes an AoO due to being Tripped (via *[Greater Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-trip-combat-final/)*)
- Once resolved, Opponent B provokes a further AoO from Player A (via *[Vicious Stomp](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/vicious-stomp-combat/)*)

I am aware that, once resolved, Opponent B would continue to Stand Up (presuming consciousness remains).
My question stems from having the ability to Trip a prone creature (due to there being no text saying you *cannot* Trip a prone creature), and how the Trip text specifies the result of tripping a creature:

> **Trip**
>   You can attempt to trip your opponent in place of a melee attack. *You can only trip an opponent who is no more than one size category larger than you.* ... If your attack exceeds the target’s CMD, *the target is knocked prone.*

Comment: I am marking this as a duplicate, because thought it sounds like a different specific case, the confusion caused by the same question: *Can you trip again a creature that is trying to stand up?* and we already have an answer for that.

Comment: Yeah, that seems fair. I didn't find this with my initial search, probably because I was looking for questions related to attacks of opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer to [this related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68284/is-a-trip-still-considered-successful-even-if-the-target-is-already-prone) suggests you simply can't trip a prone target.

Considering you could trip, you couldn't apply Vicious Stomp in this situation. Vicious Stomp triggers "whenever an opponent falls prone adjacent to you", "falls prone" meaning "is not prone and then becomes prone", which doesn't happen here.